# Golfing Chain (Cops' Thread)

Tags: code-golf, sequence, cops-and-robbers

This is a Cops and Robbers challenge. For the Robbers' thread, go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166340/42963).

The Cops have three tasks.
1) Pick a sequence from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).

2) Pick a language (this is suggested to be a golflang, but doesn't have to be) that, when given input `n`, outputs `A(n)` (where `A(n)` is the sequence chosen) using all usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules.
Call this language **L<sub>A</sub>** and code **C<sub>A</sub>**.
For example, *Jelly* and *Jelly_code*.

3) Then, pick a different language (this is suggested to be a non-golflang, but doesn't have to be) and write code that takes no input and outputs code **C<sub>A</sub>**, again following all usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules. (Note: this can be obfuscated code and doesn't necessarily need to be golfed, but the longer this code is the easier it will be for the robbers to crack your submission.)
Call this language **L<sub>B</sub>** and code **C<sub>B</sub>**.
For example, *Python* and *Python_code*.

**The Cop's submission to this challenge** is the sequence (specified whether 0- or 1-indexed), the name of the two languages **L<sub>A</sub>** and **L<sub>B</sub>** (and which one solves which part), and the byte-count of **C<sub>B</sub>** only. Keep the actual code of both parts, and the length of **C<sub>A</sub>**, secret.

For the Cop, links to documentation for **L<sub>A</sub>** and **L<sub>B</sub>**, or an interpreter (or a TIO link, since that includes both), are appreciated but not required.

The Robber's challenge is to select a Cops' entry and write code **C<sub>C</sub>** in the same **L<sub>B</sub>** language that outputs *some* code in the same **L<sub>A</sub>** language that solves the original OEIS task. The length of **C<sub>C</sub>** can be no longer than the length of **C<sub>B</sub>** as revealed by the cop (though may be shorter). Note: The code produced by **C<sub>C</sub>** does *not* have to match **C<sub>A</sub>**.

For our example, this means that the Robber has to write *Python* code that outputs *Jelly* code that solves the original OEIS sequence, and that *Python* code has to be no longer than the length revealed by the Cop.

#### Winning conditions

Answers that have not been cracked in a week can have their solutions revealed, at which point they are considered *Safe*. Note that if you don't reveal your solution after a week, it can still be cracked. The Cop with the shortest *Safe* answer wins.

Comment: Reminds me of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128065/46066

Comment: Do we keep the OEIS sequence secret?

Comment: @juniorRubyist No, the Cop must state which sequence they used, and whether it's 0- or 1-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166384/58563) by [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

Let's try it the other way around: golflang generates non-golflang.

> ***a(n)** = number of partitions of **n** (the partition numbers).*

- **a(n)** (0-indexed) is returned by a **JavaScript** function (ES6)
- The program that outputs the JS function is written in [**Jelly**](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)
- The length of the Jelly program is **35 bytes**

### Intended solution

> Jelly: `“¦ṚoIwƭ- ḊFæSḂ¥¶Ẉ|ḊJƓƝʋnrB⁾’b28+40Ọ`
>
>
>     which outputs
>
>
>     JS: `C=(A,B=A)=>A<0?0:A?B?C(A,B-1)+C(A-B,B):0:1`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166384/42545). That was quite fun, although I seem to have lost a couple of hours :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Nice! My JS solution was using a restricted range of characters so that it can be compressed as a base-28 integer on the Jelly side.

Comment: @ETHproductions Man, I should have spent more time optimizing the JS code. Here is a [31-byte](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9qZWxsef//4oCcNcaKMsKhZcW74bqLyZPFksin4bqPe8OR4oG4xpHDhMm84bijZ8SX4bmY4bq44oCZYjI4KzQw4buM//8) solution. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## [OEIS 000035](http://oeis.org/A000035), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166355/68942) by [betseg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56721/betseg)

The problem is solved in **Proton**.
The Proton code is output by **Python**.
The length of the Python program is **13 bytes**.

Really easy one for starters (if you know Proton :D). Zero-indexed.

## Intended Solution

> Python: `print("(2%)")`
>  Proton: `(2%)`
>  Though I decided to let `n=>n%2` be short enough because dyadic/monadic function shortcuts are not documented.

Comment: Really easy one if you know a language which appears to have precisely zero documentation. Yeah, great.

Comment: Why is the link to A34 ...

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166355/56721)

Comment: @user202729 fixed thanks

Comment: @PeterTaylor [precisely zero](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton/wiki) there's enough here for you to solve it...

Answer (score 2):

## [OEIS A048272](https://oeis.org/A048272), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166362/31716) by [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)

> Number of odd divisors of **n** minus number of even divisors of **n** (1-indexed).

- The program that outputs **a(n)** is written in **[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)**.
- The program that outputs the 05AB1E program is written in **[Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak)** + the `-A` flag.
- The length of the Brain-Flak program is **198 bytes** (the byte count does *not* include the flag).

Note that I could probably easily golf the Brain-Flak program by using stack-manipluation tricks and other kolmogorov-complexity tricks I am aware of, but I wanted to keep this simple as my first submission. <s>Good luck, robbers!</s>

#### What I had in mind

> 05AB1E: `ÑÈD<)O(O` 
>  
>  Brain-Flak: `(((((((((((()()()){}){}){({}[()])}{}())[((((()()()){}){}())){}{}])((((()()()){}){}())){}{})[((((()()()){}){})()){}{}])(((()()()){})){}{}())(()()()()){})(((((()()()()){}){}){}()){}){})((()()())){}{})`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166362/31716)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem :( I just finished

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Nice! I'll try something a bit harder next.

Answer (score 2):

## [OEIS A000034](https://oeis.org/A000034) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166975/3852) by H.PWiz)

> **1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, …**
>
> *Period 2: repeat [1, 2]; a(n) = 1 + (n mod 2).*

**a(n)** is the output of a [**Haskell**](https://tio.run/#haskell) answer, which is the output of a 32-byte [**Malbolge**](https://tio.run/#malbolge) answer.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166975/71256)

Answer (score 1):

## [OEIS A000668](https://oeis.org/A000668), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166968/3852) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)

> Mersenne primes (of form **2<sup>p</sup>-1** where **p** is a prime)

- **a(n)** is outputted by a **[Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)** full program.
- **n** is 1-indexed.
- The Jelly program is printed by a **[Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity)** program, whose length is **38 bytes**.

Different strategy: solve the sequence in a golflang and output the program in an esolang.

#### Intended solution

> - **[Jelly code](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/tUcMMm4e7Jh3bpPxw56r//00B)**
> - **[Triangularity code](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTwGIufT0lB7uXKUEYik93DXp2CZlJT0uJbVHDTNslLS1//8HAA)**

Comment: Are you sure the length is correct? The docs say a Triangularity program must have length `2*n^2 - 1` which can't be 38.

Comment: @Lynn That refers to *character count*, not *byte count*.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166968/3852)

Answer (score 1):

## [OEIS A055642](https://oeis.org/A055642), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166965/80897) by [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)

> Number of digits in decimal expansion of n

This is probably too easy, but it took me a while so I hope someone out there will be just as disappointed as I was when I finally figured it out :D

- The program that writes out **a(n)** is written in **[05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)**
- The program that prints the 05AB1E program is written in **[TeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX)**
- The TeX program is **6 bytes** long

What I had in mind:

> `Sg` as 05AB1E code
>  `Sg\bye` as TeX code

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166965/3852)

Comment: @Lynn yes. How disappointed were you?