# Golfing Chain (Robbers' Thread)

Tags: code-golf, sequence, cops-and-robbers

This is a Cops and Robbers challenge. For the Cops' thread, go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/166338/42963).

The Cops have three tasks.
1) Pick a sequence from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).

2) Pick a language (this is suggested to be a golflang, but doesn't have to be) that, when given input `n`, outputs `A(n)` (where `A(n)` is the sequence chosen) using all usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules.
Call this language **L<sub>A</sub>** and code **C<sub>A</sub>**.
For example, *Jelly* and *Jelly_code*.

3) Then, pick a different language (this is suggested to be a non-golflang, but doesn't have to be) and write code that takes no input and outputs code **C<sub>A</sub>**, again following all usual [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules. (Note: this can be obfuscated code and doesn't necessarily need to be golfed, but the longer this code is the easier it will be for the robbers to crack your submission.)
Call this language **L<sub>B</sub>** and code **C<sub>B</sub>**.
For example, *Python* and *Python_code*.

The Cop's submission to this challenge is the sequence (specified whether 0- or 1-indexed), the name of the two languages **L<sub>A</sub>** and **L<sub>B</sub>** (and which one solves which part), and the byte-count of **C<sub>B</sub>** only. Keep the actual code of both parts, and the length of **C<sub>A</sub>**, secret.

**The Robber's challenge** is to select a Cops' entry and write code **C<sub>C</sub>** in the same **L<sub>B</sub>** language that outputs *some* code in the same **L<sub>A</sub>** language that solves the original OEIS task. The length of **C<sub>C</sub>** can be no longer than the length of **C<sub>B</sub>** as revealed by the cop (though may be shorter). Note: The code produced by **C<sub>C</sub>** does *not* have to match **C<sub>A</sub>**.

For our example, this means that the Robber has to write *Python* code that outputs *Jelly* code that solves the original OEIS sequence, and that *Python* code has to be no longer than the length revealed by the Cop.

#### Winning conditions

The Robber with the most cracked solutions wins.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 90 bytes by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166358/31716)

```
((((((((((()()()){}){}){({}[()])}{}())[(((()()()){})){}{}()]))){}{}()()())([][][]){})[][])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMBNEFQs7oWjDSqa6M1NGM1a6trgYLRKPJADBKN1YSxwBIa0bEgCFIApv///6/rCAA)

This outputs:

```
ÑÉ·<O
```

First 05AB1E answer!

### How does it work?

Let's say we have 24 as input.

```
Ñ       # Divisors. 
        # Stack: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]
 É      # Odd?
        # Stack: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ·     # Double
        # Stack: [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   <    # Decrement
        # Stack: [1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
    O   # Sum
        # Stack: -4
```

The brain-flak code mostly just uses tricks to push large numbers in few bytes. It was very convenient (and unintentional) that the ASCII values are mostly increasing:

```
209
201
183
60
79
```

It's also nice that `60 * 3 ~=~ 183` so tripling it and adding a few can save a ton of bytes.

```
((((((

    # Push 79
    ((((()()()){}){}){({}[()])}{}())
    # Minus 19 (60)

    [(((()()()){})){}{}()])
    # Push that two extra times
    ))

    # Push that ^ (60) Plus the two extras popped (60 + 120 == 180)...
    {}{}
    # + 3 (183)
    ()()())

    # Plus stack-height * 3 * 2 == 3 * 3 * 2 == 18 (201)
    ([][][]){})

    # Plus stack-height * 2 == 4 * 2 == 8 (209)
    [][])
```

Comment: oh nice my 05AB1E program was 8 bytes. idk any of the 05AB1E builtins /shrug :P

Comment: [Here's 80](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMoiGUJghqVtdqaoLI6loNzVgNDRBDsxpIRQO5mmBRTZAysApNjehYEARpAtP////XdQQA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: [Here's 72](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMMoiGUhiYIampW14JwdS2IHauhAWKC@ZpQWSBLIzoWBEFKwfT///91HQE "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 bytes by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166374/42545)

Managed a byte shorter than his solution!

```
“`Ḃ|⁴ʂⱮdÐỌK_ƬƬfıæh’ṃ“fnk1()+-,=>?:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9qZWxsef//4oCcYOG4gnzigbTKguKxrmTDkOG7jEtfxqzGrGbEscOmaOKAmeG5g@KAnGZuazEoKSstLD0@Pzr//w)

This outputs the JS function

```
f=(n,k=1)=>n>=k?f(n-k,k)+f(n,k+1):1>n
```

which computes [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041) (0-indexed; `nn(0)` returns `true` in place of `1`).

Answer (score 2):

## [TeX by Simon Klaver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166962/3852)

```
g\bye
```

prints `g`, which computes the length of the input in 05AB1E.

Answer (score 2):

## [Malbolge, 32 bytes by Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166972/71256)

```
('%$:?>7[5|981Uv.uQrq)Mnmm$Hj4ED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19DXVXFyt7OPNq0xtLCMLRMrzSwqFDTNy83V8Ujy8TV5f9/AA)

That prints the following haskell function:

```
gcd 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPz05RcHof25iZp6CrUJuYoGvgkZBUWZeiV6apkK0oZ6eoYFB7P9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

I used [this](http://zb3.me/malbolge-tools/#generator) online tool to generate the Malbolge

Comment: I used the same tool :) I was hoping not many people know about it.

Answer (score 1):

### [Python, 13 bytes by HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166344/56721)

```python
print"n=>n%2"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKc/WLk/VSOn/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangularity by Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166950/3852), 36 bytes

```
... ...
..  "..
.aẒ;Ba.
1ÇP$#Ṁ"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTwGIuYCUghKITny4a5K1U6Iel@Hh9gAV5Yc7G5T@/wcA)

Prints Jelly code:

```
..
.aẒ;Ba.
1ÇP$#Ṁ
```

[Try the Jelly code online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19Pj0sv8eGuSdZOiXpchofbA1SUH@5s@P//vykA) It's quite slow.

Comment: Most definitely not what I was thinking of but congrats! I'll include the intended solution in my answer shortly.